# Twice more than

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> 1. I read the reports twice more than you.
> 2. I read twice more reports than you.

I thought there are difference between two sentences. The first one means the number of the reports is twice more than the report you read but the second one means that for example if you read the reports one time I read them two times. Is my thoughts correct or Isn’t there any difference between them?

Comment: Neither texts are valid English utterances. I think you probably mean *I read twice as many reports as you [do].* Where it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include the auxiliary ***do*** at the end. It "stands for" *...as you do **read*** - including *both* verbs would be positively archaic, but *some* speakers would sometimes end with ***...as you read***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Agreed. (1) could also mean _I read the reports twice as  many times as you do_ (meaning 'a particular set of reports').

Comment: When you say "read", do you mean it in the simple past or present simple?

Comment: @KateBunting: Or even *I spend **twice as long** reading the daily reports as you do* - perhaps implying I read them more *carefully* than you, even if we both read each report once only, missing none.

Comment: I think it could be put compactly *I read twice the reports you do.* (Referring to number of reports read.)

Answer (score 2):

Neither texts are valid English utterances. However, they can be slightly modified to make more sense.

1. I read the reports twice more than you.

Could be

"I read the reports twice *as many times as* you *do/did*."

Depending on whether read is past tense, or present tense, it would be "did" or "do".

And it means there are exactly X reports, let's say 10 reports, and one person reads those same reports *more times*.

2. I read twice more reports than you.

Could be

"I read twice *as many reports as* you *(do/did).*"

This means one person read 10 reports, and the other person read 20 reports.